# Judge the performance of SVR in R

Tags: r, regression, svm

I am analyzing a dataset by using support vector regression in R and try hard to figure out the answers to the following points... but in vain so far. Any help and guidance will be deeply appreciated.

**(1) How to judge the general performance of SVR (after using tune() function to get the best one)?**   
I knew that, unlike the straightforward R square in OLS, there is no default R square in SVR, and thus we should use "MSE"/"MAPE" (calculated based on test dataset) to measure the performance of SVR. BUT the question is:  
*(a)* how low should MSE be? Are there any criteria?  
*(b)* would it make sense to calculate the R square manually for SVR?

**(2) How to judge the performance of each input feature?**
  
*(a)* Unlike the coefficient (and p-value) showing the influence of each feature in OLS, the only way (I found so far) to pin down the importance by using the `Importance()` function in `rminer` package. Are there any other indicators of input-feature performance?  
*(b)* In addition, even I read through the `rminer` package's manual, I still don't know how to interpret the results of `Importance ()` function.  
Please refer to the following code and results; this SVR has 3 input features, but `$value` and `$imp` shows the results of "4" features, how come? Also, how to interpret the value of 0 (e.g. higher the `$value`, higher the importance)?

```
model_try_svr <- fit(price_total~landarea_m2+floorarea_m2+buildcover_rate,data=train_hp, model="svm",kpar=list(sigma=0.10), C=2)
svm.imp <- Importance(model_try_svr, data=train_hp,method="1D-SA",measure="AAD")
svm.imp

$value
[1]    0     1493723  17922779    0
$imp
[1] 0.00000000 0.01230708 0.14766928 0.00000000
```

Thank you for taking time reading this post. I have been struggling in finding the answers to these questions. Any guidance will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Concerning your comment in section (1): Please note that measuring performance using the MSE of our test set is not an alternative to R squared. MSE is model agnostic, as it compares predictions and actual values and can be used even if your model is a linear regression one. Also, R squared is straightforward only based on the train set (as it is part of the model output). Interpreting that R squared might lead to overfitting. You should measure performance based on a test set even when your metric is R squared.

Comment: @AntoniosK, thank you for the prompt feedback. Just like we can use R2 to measure OLS performance, is there any indicator that can measure the general performance of SVR?

Comment: No, nothing so straightforward.